# In KDE, how can I make totem the lowest priority program in all associated file types

Tags: unity, kde, default-programs, file-association

I just installed the ubuntu-desktop package on Kubuntu to try out unity, but now all my file associations have been stolen from my (painstakingly optimised) defaults (amarok, k3b, dragon player) to (factory default) things like totem, brasero and movie player. Is there a way to quickly lower the priority of ALL of these programs without uninstalling them? Uninstalling doesn't seem to be an option, as doing so wants to remove unity as well.

Thank you very much to anyone who can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Zorael" is explaining how to "Quckly change Application Preference Order": http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1333363

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for - guess I should have tried in the ubuntu forums, not here.
For others' reference, I added the line `InitialPreference=0` to the 'totem.desktop', 'banshee.desktop' and 'brasero.desktop' files in `~/.local/share/applications/`. This seemed to work.